# this is undefined in a member function

Tags: typescript

```
export class AccessController extends BaseController {
  appContext!: AppContext;
  constructor(appContext: AppContext) {
    super(appContext);
    this.appContext = appContext;
  }
  public async generateAccess(data, _) {
    return this.appContext.accessService.generate()
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
export const accessController = new accessController(appContext);
export const generateAccess =
  functions
      .region(Constant.REGION.toString())
      .https
      .onCall(accessController.generateAccess);
```

Any idea why `this` is undefined in the member function and how do I solve this?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.That solved my issue

Comment: for anyone from the future. used an arrow function inside onCall